# Struts2 Validation Framework doesn't validate Fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I m new to Struts2. I want to use Validation Framework for a simple 'register' form. Here is my JSP page form elements;

```
    <s:form action="register">
            <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" />
            <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" />
            <s:textfield name="email" label="email"/>
            <s:submit value="Register" />
        </s:form>  
 validation error ? = <s:actionerror /><br/>
        ---Action Message--- <s:actionmessage/>
```

Here is struts2.xml file;

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
       <package name="default" extends="struts-default">        
        <action name="register"
                class="com.action.RegisterAction">
                <result name="success">home.jsp</result>    
                <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
                </action>     
       </package>
</struts>
```

*RegisterAction* class has

- String name;
- int age;
- String email;  variables with getters and setters. And its execute() just returns *SUCCESS*

For these fields validations the following validation xml file is used, for now only one field *name* is checked. Name of the validation file is `RegisterAction-validation.xml`

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<!-- Author: Aash -->     
<validators>     
    <field name="name">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>name is required.. :) </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>    
</validators>
```

Here is the project structure  [image]

Please any one let me know how can I come up with this. Thanks in advance.

**New Add** : According to the struts.xml, if there is an error,(the validation says something is wrong), the page should be redirected to *index.jsp* ,but when nothing is given for the field 'name', still it goes to home.jsp .

**A Solution Found**
I added to validation.xml
`!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" 
        "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">`

But it is displayed on the top of Form, I don't know why not printed as `actionError`. How I get it Printed where I want it to view(example : bottom of the form)?

Comment: You may need to provide more details. Consider putting your project on github so we can take a look; without too much thought it seems like it should work. For completeness, it wouldn't redirect to index, rather it will forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a field Error, as you have put elements in the JSP page, the message comes close to the field 'name' . If you wanna get printed it,where u want it to be,  `<s:fielderror fieldName="name" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the xml file name. It should be `RegisterAction-validation.xml`

Comment: I don't see anything else wrong. Do you close the `<validators>` tag in your `RegisterAction-validation.xml`?? I guess that's just a copy/paste mistake, but just in case...

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/basic-validation.html) says, the DOCTYPE should be there in the validation.xml.
`<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
-->`

Answer (score 0):

Put parameter validate value make 'true; in in `<s:form action="register" validate="true">`